# xcode 7 TableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7

does anyone know how to add a UIPickerViewDataSource and a UIPickerViewDelegate to the class of TableViewController

```
class AddProductTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate
```

because when I do it like that it keeps giving me an error of type 'AddProductTableViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource' it gives me the same error for the UIPickerViewDelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement all the required methods of `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`, if you want to conform to these protocols.

```
- numberOfComponentsInPickerView:

- pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:
...
```